# Excel 2016: Calculate the median of a peer group by combining two measures

Tags: microsoft-excel

I got a test file with 10 companies. I want to calculate the median by combining TA and ROE. The objective is to find the 5 companies closest to the target company in terms of TA and then the 3 companies from those 5 which are closest in terms of ROE! I already have the formula for calculating the median of the 3 companies closest to the firm to be valued in terms of TA and ROE, respectively (see columns I and J).

e.g. for the 3 (=N3) companies next to the target in terms of TA: {=MEDIAN(IF(IF($B$4:$B$15=B4;"";ABS(E4-$E$4:$E$15))<=SMALL(IF($B$4:$B$15=B4;"";ABS(E4-$E$4:$E$15));$N$3);$G$4:$G$15;""))}

Any idea how to solve that problem?
Test file available here: https://we.tl/rNIrgWL9h8
Thank you so much for helping out guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do this with a single formula it becomes a bit of a monster.....but you can use this array formula in `L4` copied down

`=MEDIAN(IF($B$4:$B$15<>B4,IF(ABS(E4-$E$4:$E$15)<=SMALL(IF($B$4:$B$15<>B4,ABS(E4-$E$4:$E$15)),5),IF(ABS(F4-$F$4:$F$15)<=SMALL(IF($B$4:$B$15<>B4,IF(ABS(E4-$E$4:$E$15)<=SMALL(IF($B$4:$B$15<>B4,ABS(E4-$E$4:$E$15)),5),ABS(F4-$F$4:$F$15))),3),$G$4:$G$15))))`

Note that as with your formulas if you calculate the closest 3 this way (by comparing against the 3rd highest value) then it's possible you might actually include 4 or more when there are ties on the 3rd smallest number.

Comment: Thank you very much for helping barry. However, since I want to keep this formula modifiable regarding the number of firms used, I changed the parameters (e.g. to get the 3 closest and then the 2 closest) and tried to reconcile the results manually. Unfortunately, it's not matching...

Comment: Hi @Moritz, I just ran through your problem myself and while my solution is slightly different from barry houdini's (I used column C for my list instead of column B), my results were identical to his in your test data. Perhaps you can provide some expected results for the sample data?

Comment: @Nayrb I actually started with C too but I reckoned that B would be better as it already is used in the formula to disregard current row - obviously can use either as long as the values are not repeated

Comment: @Moritz - I checked pretty thoroughly that the formula works, are you taking account of my last paragraph of my answer - by the, nature of the formula logic you may have 6 companies that are <= 5th smallest - because of ties?

Comment: I tested again and found a simpler way to do this - I've edited my formula above to show the simplified version - note that it gets exactly the same results as the previous one. Also if you want to change the n values note that the 5 appears twice

Comment: @barryhoudini it's no problem if there are more than 3 firms in case the numbers for the 3rd and 4th are equal compared to the target! However, that is highly unlikely.
Thank you so much for the adjusted formula. I also checked it with my small sample and think it's working properly. Applied it to my full sample and didn't get any errors. AWESOME! Thank you very much!

Comment: @Moritz - happy it works - if all is OK can you accept my answer please?